# c# : avoid branching while iterating on a dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

I have the below code in which i branch for each sample in a dictionary , is there a way either by using LINQ or any other method in which i can avoid branching -> may be a functional approach

```
Dictionary<string, int> samples = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
    {"a", 1},
    {"aa", 2},
    {"b", 1},
    {"bb", 3}
};

foreach (var sample in samples)
{
    if (sample.Value ==)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("sample passed");
    }
    else if (sample.Value == 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("sample isolated");
    }
    else if (sample.Value == 3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("sample biased");
    }
}
```

**UPD**

What if i have other type of comprasion:

```
foreach (var sample in samples)
{
    if (sample.Value <= 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("sample passed");
    }
    else if (sample.Value <= 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("sample isolated");
    }
    else if (sample.Value <= 3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("sample biased");
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to avoid branching or writing if-else statements?

Comment: @Guru Stron avoid any kind of branching , if - else , switch etc

Comment: `Dictionary<int, string>` messages = new Dictionary<int, string> { { 1, "passed" }, { 2, "isolated" }, { 3, "biased"} };` then just do `Console.Writeline($"sample {messages[sample.Value]}");`

Comment: @itsme86 i just made console for illustration , but it can be a different functionality executed

Comment: @KeshavRaghav the idea is still the same. You create another container which stores your key-value pairs, where both can be almost anything.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create a list of `Action`s that you wish to perform, then execute them based on the index.  This way your methods can be quite varied.  If you need to perform very similar actions for each option, then storing a list of values would be a better than storing Actions.

```
List<Action> functions = new List<Action>();
functions.Add(() => Console.WriteLine("sample passed"));
functions.Add(() => Console.WriteLine("sample isolated"));
functions.Add(() => Console.WriteLine("sample biased"));

foreach (var sample in samples)
{
  Action actionToExecute = functions[sample.Value - 1];
  actionToExectute();
}
```

If you wanted to use a dictionary as your comment implies:

```
Dictionary<int, Action> functions = new Dictionary<int, Action>();
functions.Add(1, () => Console.WriteLine("sample passed"));
functions.Add(2, () => Console.WriteLine("sample isolated"));
functions.Add(3, () => Console.WriteLine("sample biased"));

foreach (var sample in samples)
{
  Action actionToExecute = functions[sample.Value];
  actionToExectute();
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the `- 1` for index.

Comment: i would rather use a dictionary to store the actions , rather than a list so that index wont be ugly ?

Comment: I don't see a problem with that.  If that makes it easier to understand then I'm all for it.  The implementation would be nearly identical to what I've written.

Comment: @KeshavRaghav please see update of my post. According to [referencesource.microsoft.com](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,179) there still will be internal branching if you use `Dictionary` as container for your mapping =). But if you will not have misses branch prediction should take care of it.

Comment: ah i am still looking if linq can step in to do something more flexible , to remove the foreach too

Comment: @KeshavRaghav there is a lot of internal if-elses inside linq functions.

Comment: @GuruStron I get the impression the OP is interested in how to create code that isn't branching, not the internal workings.

Comment: But if you call method which is branching then your code is branching, no? =)

Comment: @GuruStron Yes, but it depends on what your goal is.  If you just prefer that your code "looks nice" or have a preference for not doing long if/else statements then it doesn't matter if the assembly code is branching.

Comment: @MikeH OP stated in the comments "@Guru Stron avoid any kind of branching , if - else , switch etc" so I can interpret it either way =)

Comment: @GuruStron  i modified the question so that dictionary wont be a fit here

Comment: @KeshavRaghav if you can't provide function that transforms your input in some kind of key without branching, than you will need to have  branching somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

For this concrete case you can introduce another map(`Dictionary` or an array, as I did):

```
Dictionary<string, int> samples = new Dictionary<string, int>()
            {
                {"a", 1},
                {"aa", 2},
                {"b", 1},
                {"bb", 3}
            };

var map = new []
{
    "sample passed",
    "sample isolated",
    "sample biased"
};
foreach (var sample in samples)
{
    Console.WriteLine(map[sample.Value - 1]);
}
```

As for actual code it highly depends on usecases and how you want to handle faulty situations.

**UPD**

It seems that if you will be using dictionary for your map there still [will be some branching](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,179), but if you will not have misses branch prediction should take care of it.

Comment: This is better than my answer if your actions are going to be similar for each case.

Comment: @MikeH the main here is idea. And it is the same =)

Answer (score 0):

So you have a `Dictionary<string, int>`. Every item in the dictionary is a `KeyValuePair<string, int>`. I assume that the string is the name of the sample (identifier), and the int is a number that says something about the sample:

- if the number equals 0 or 1, the sample is qualified as Passed;
- if the number equals 2, then you call it Isolated
- if the number equals 3, then you call it Biased.

All higher numbers are not interesting for you.

You want to group the samples in Passed / Isolated / Biased samples.

Whenever you have a sequence of similar items and you want to make groups of items, where every element has something in common with the other elements in the group, consider using  one of the overloads of [Enumerable.GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1)

Let's first define an enum to hold your qualifications, and a method that converts the integer value of the sample into the enum:

```
enum SampleQualification
{
    Passed,
    Isolated,
    Biased,
}

SampleQualification FromNumber(int number)
{
    switch (number)
    {
        case 2:
            return SampleQualification.Isolated;
        case 3:
            return SampleQualification.Biased;
        default:
            return SampleQualification.Passed;
    }
}
```

Ok, so you have your dictionary of samples, where every key is a name of the sample and the value is a number that can be converted to a SampleQualification.

```
Dictionary<string, int> samples = ...
var qualifiedSamples = samples // implements IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>>

    // keep only samples with Value 0..3
    .Where(sample => 0 <= sample.Value && sample.Value <= 3)

    // Decide where the sample is Passed / Isolated / Biased
    .Select(sample => new
    {
        Qualification = FromNumber(sample.Value)
        Name = sample.Key,           // the name of the sample
        Number = sample.Value,

    })

    // Make groups of Samples with same Qualification:
    .GroupBy(
        // KeySelector: make groups with same qualification:
        sample => sample.Qualification,

        // ResultSelector: take the qualification, and all samples with this qualification
        // to make one new:
        (qualification, samplesWithThisQualification) => new
        {
            Qualification = qualification,
            Samples = samplesWithThisQualification.Select(sample => new
            {
                Name = sample.Name,
                Number = sample.Number,
            })
            .ToList(),
         });
```

The result is a sequence of items. Where every item has a property Qualification, which holds Passed / Isolated / Biased. Every item also has a list of samples that have this qualification.

```
// Process Result
foreach (var qualifiedSample in qualifiedSamples)
{
    Console.WriteLine("All samples with qualification " + qualifiedSample.Qualification);
    foreach (var sample in qualifiedSample.Samples)
    {
        Console.WriteLine({0} - {1}, sample.Name, sample.Value);
    }
}
```